# How to decode a R dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataframe with values of certain columns (SNPs - Single Nucleotide Polymorphism ) are encoded as 1,2 and 3 like the following.. (just selected 2 columns out of 100s)

[image]

I have another data frame for the genotypes of these codes for each SNP as the following

[image]

Now I want to decode the codes 1,2 and 3 in the dataframe `gt` according to the dataframe `gt_codes` and make a data frame like the following

[image]

I have given sample data as `dput`. Can someone please help me.

```
structure(list(rs2278426..DOCK6. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), rs1122326..HSPB9. = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


structure(list(rs_id = c("rs2278426..DOCK6.", "rs2278426..DOCK6.", 
"rs2278426..DOCK6.", "rs1122326..HSPB9.", "rs1122326..HSPB9.", 
"rs1122326..HSPB9."), code = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), gt = c("AA", 
"AT", "TT", "AA", "AT", "TT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on

2. reshaping your original data from wide to long,
3. doing a join with the mapping table `gt_codes` to replace old with new values, and then
4. reshaping data again back from long to wide.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%  
    mutate(row = 1:n()) %>%
    pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "rs_id", values_to = "code") %>%
    left_join(gt_codes, by = c("rs_id", "code")) %>%
    select(-code) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "rs_id", values_from = "gt") %>%
    select(-row)
## A tibble: 10 × 2
#   rs2278426..DOCK6. rs1122326..HSPB9.
#   <chr>             <chr>            
# 1 AA                AC               
# 2 AA                AA               
# 3 AA                AA               
# 4 AA                AA               
# 5 AA                AC               
# 6 AA                AA               
# 7 AA                AA               
# 8 AT                AC               
# 9 AA                AA               
#10 AA                AA
```

---

### Sample data

```r
gt_codes <- data.frame(
    rs_id = c(rep("rs2278426..DOCK6.", 3), rep("rs1122326..HSPB9.", 3)),
    code = c(1:3, 1:3),
    gt = c("AA", "AT", "TT", "AA", "AC", "CC"))

df <- structure(list(rs2278426..DOCK6. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), rs1122326..HSPB9. = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```